# Append return values to jQuery Deferred/ Callbacks

Tags: jquery, memory, callback, deferred

Is there any way to add to the memory of a jQuery Callbacks object? For example if there is a jQuery Callbacks object with the memory flag set, is there a way to add a value to the memory in one of the callback functions in the list so that the next function that runs will get the additional value?

I want to basically add an additional argument to give to the failFilter function at the end of a Deferred then chain without returning a new rejected Deferred object.

What I'm currently doing:

```
deferred.then(null, function(error, errorType){
    errorType = typeof(errorType) === "undefined" ? "INDEXEDDB_ERROR" : errorType;
    return new jQuery.Deferred().reject(error, errorType);
});
```

What I would like to do:

```
deferred.then(null, function(error, errorType){
    errorType = typeof(errorType) === "undefined" ? "INDEXEDDB_ERROR" : errorType;
    return [error, errorType];
});
```

and basically have the error handler at the end of the deferred then chain to receive both `error` and `errorType` as arguments

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to return anything from a fail callback. Did you intend to instead use `.then`? `.fail` is not a filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, even using .then, the only way to have it return as two arguments rather than an array as the first argument is by creating a new deferred.

Comment: The examples are part of a function in a then chain. So I would have something like `fcn().then(fcn2).then(fcn3)...then(null, errorHandler).` In each of the fcns I return a deferred's promise with it's .fail defined instead of defining a failFilter in the second argument of `then`

Comment: The function in `.fail` is defined that way so that the first (or original) error that occurred in the chain gets passed down to `errorHandler` at the end without being changed by the failCallbacks of the other promises in the then chain

Comment: @KevinB sorry about that, you were right, I did apparently mean `.then` after doing further research. I guess I'll just continue to return a new deferred object. I wish there was a more elegant way though.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to ensure that `error` was an object such that it could convey any amount of meaning, eg `error.message` and `error.type`?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I ended up doing just that, you're right, having an error object eliminates the need to return a new rejected deferred since I'm returning just one thing. Didn't know why I couldn't think of that in the first place...

Comment: @karimp please consider posting what you ended up doing as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since there isn't any way to pass multiple arguments in a jQuery Deferred `then()` error callback without passing in a new deferred object, I decided to take @Beetroot-Beetroots suggestion and wrap the error in an object with a `type` to indicate the error type and a `pass` property to not process the error and pass it on to the next handler

i.e.

```
deferred.then(/*success callback*/, function(error){
    error = error || null;
    if (typeof(error.pass) === "undefined"){
        error = {
            error: arugments,
            type: "indexedDb",
            pass: true
        };
    }
    return error;
});
```

Comment: Upvoted for gratitude for posting what you did as it is very useful for future users. I have to wonder though, why are you simply not throwing the error (promises are throw safe, and will propagate rejections) and subclassing the error object? What you're doing is missing on stack traces etc. Your errors should always be `Error`s.